# I dont know how to use fetch_message correctly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I dont know where to put the Coroutine "`fetch_message`"
I want to edit a message, but it doesnt work the old way

I tried the old way, but it told me it got 2 positional arguments instead of 1...

```
creator = ctx.message.author.id
await channel.send(f"<@{creator}>", embed=embed)

message_channel = ctx.message.channel
destruction_message = await message_channel .send("Self destruct in 3")
message = await client.fetch_message(destruction_message)
time.sleep(1)
print(message)
print(destruction_message)

await message.edit("Self destruct in 2")
message.edit()
time.sleep(1)
await message.edit("Self destruct in 1")
time.sleep(1)
await message.delete()
message = ctx.message
await client.message.delete(message )
```

It just tells me "`AttributeError: module 'client' has no attribute 'fetch_message'`"

This code is part of a embed message, everything including The "`Self destruct in 3`" gets posted, but the editing fails...

Comment: Where's fetch_message in your code?

Comment: Wait a second ill give you the code with fetch

Comment: It is there now, forgot it before

Answer (score 3):

The [fetch_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message) method is an [Abstract Base Class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message), more precice a `Messageable`.

According to the documentation

> An ABC that details the common operations on a model that can send
> messages.
>
> The following implement this ABC:
>
> ```
> • TextChannel
> • DMChannel
> • GroupChannel
> • User
> • Member
> • Context
> ```

This means you can call fetch_message with an object of any of those classes.

In your case you can call it directly on the context
`await ctx.fetch_message(id)`.

A more general example starting only with ids would be:

```
    # taken out of a on_raw_reaction_add() method
    # assuming self.client is the bot

    guild = self.client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    channel = guild.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
```

However, for your case you should use BrainDeads suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why do you want to fetch message when you already got the message object with

```
message = await nachrichtchannel.send("self destruct in 3")
```

You can just call `edit` on that object, you don't have to call the `fetch_message`

For your `edit` error you have to pass `content` as an argument.
Seems like you are trying to do a counter so here's an example:

```
 @commands.command()
 async def counter(self, ctx):
     message = await ctx.channel.send("Timer 3")
     await asyncio.sleep(1)

     await message.edit(content="Timer 2")
     await asyncio.sleep(1)

     await message.edit(content="Timer 1")
     await asyncio.sleep(1)

     await message.delete()
```

You should use `await asyncio.sleep(1)` instead of `time.sleep(1)` to avoid any code hangups.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the "(content="...")", so python thought it was another positional argument... I tried without fetch before, but now everything works! Thank you.

Comment: @B4shPlays np, btw I edited my answer. I suggest using await asyncio.sleep(1)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to properly use `fetch_message` correctly